# phrase usage: "to what extent" followed by "to that extent"

Tags: phrase-usage

The MW dictionary defines an adverbal sense of "the":

> 2a: to what extent
> *the sooner the better*
>
> b: to that extent
> *the sooner the better*

Does this mean I can make a phrase like:

> To what extent you love John, to that extent he loves you

Is that okay? Can "to what extent" be followed by "to that extent"? to express the idea that you love John the same amount as John loves you.

Comment: What are you trying to say with this? It doesn't appear to make much sense. Perhaps you wanted "to the extent that he loves you", but even then I don't know what you are trying to say.

Comment: @JamesK You could check out the adverb sense of "the" in Merriam-Webster's dictionary: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the

Comment: I've check it out... I still don't know what you are trying to say in your sentence...

Comment: If you had perused the said definition seriously, you'd have known the intended meaning of my example is, "The more you know John, the more he loves you."

Comment: Look at the example provided there: : to what extent : by how much
_**The** faster you go, the sooner you'll finish._
3: to that extent : by that much
_The more you think, **the** more you'll learn._

Comment: That was't very clear.. I've edited to reflect this.   Note, it is really your responsibility to include all that context in your question and not have it dragged out in the comments.

Comment: In theory, *To what extent you love John, to that extent he loves you* might be called "syntactically valid", but idiomatically it would simply never occur. You might feasibly find the basic construction rephrased as something like *To **the extent that** you love John, [**so**] to that extent **does he love** you*. But it would only occur in old-fashioned "poetic" contexts - it's not something appropriate for normal contexts today. Note that *The more the merrier, The sooner the better, The X the Y,...* is a "frozen form" idiom. You can't just casually rephrase / substitute ***bits*** of it.

Comment: The clarifatory edit impeded me to downvote. This is the kind of detail, research, information and effort your questions often lack.

Answer (score 1):

> Can "to what extent" be followed by "to that extent"?

In the dictionary entry, "to what extent" and "to that extent" seem to be explanatory phrases, rather than precise drop-in replacements.  Your question is if they are synonymous with "the", and so they can be used directly in the sentence. That answer is - almost.

"to what extent?" could be seen as a question, similar to "what color?" and the answer is a real color such as "green" or "blue", and not the literal phrase "*the what color* jacket".

Here are example constructions with "extent".

"*To the extent* you like John... he also likes you."

"It seems you like John a lot. *And to that same extent*, he likes you back."

---

Let's try to rewrite "the sooner the better" with "extent".

To the extent that it happens sooner, to that same extent it's definitely better.

---

So, you may use "extent" when rewording the adverbial.  Although, the resulting sentence is not as pithy and idiomatic.